# How do I set a live video as "Featured" using the DailyMotion API?

Tags: dailymotion-api

I'm trying to sort out how to update a user's "Featured Video" via the DailyMotion API.  When I'm logged into the DailyMotion site, this is a pretty straight forward process - there is a "Change Featured Video" button on the user home page.  I don't see where this is made accessible within the API.

To be as specific as possible, this is a live stream I'm creating and would like to feature.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use the `videostar` field: https://developer.dailymotion.com/documentation#user-videostar-field

You need your user to accept the `manage_videos` scope in order to do this.